# Get the data history from SQL Server and PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, history

I have a SQL Server database and I have to update information permanently of all tables in that database. After that, I have to show on my application (php) the values of some data updated with the dates exactly.

I tought about triggers, but it will not help me because I have a lot of operations in my database

Comment: Are you asking how to keep an audit log of all changes made to the data in your database?  Why wouldn't triggers which insert to audit/history tables work for you?

Comment: i have a lot of opperation and data so triggers will not support all this operation and it will makes problems in the future?

Comment: Why not?  "It will make problems" isn't really a reason.  What actual problem have you encountered?